# How to get my own data using Facebook's API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the graph API Explorer provided by Facebook

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Why can I not get my own data?

Comment: did you authorize yourself correctly? a bit more background information would be good. what steps did you take to reproduce the error?

Comment: How do you authorize yourself correctly?

Comment: there is a button called "get token"